# Get AJAX 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is my second ever attempt at trying to get AJAX to work in an app and I'm stuck. I have a link and I'm trying to render a chart. I tried with different routes but I'm pretty sure this one is the correct syntax, but I am getting the error: GET http://localhost:3000/players/getdata 404 (not found).

I am using Rails 4 if that matters.

```
<%= link_to "Show Chart", getdata_path, remote: true, method: 'GET', class: "btn" %>
```

players/getdata.js.erb

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
   ...
  });
});
```

routes.rb

```
get '/players/getdata' => 'players#getdata', as: :getdata
```

players_controller

```
def getdata
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

EDIT: rake routes gives:

```
 getdata GET    /players/getdata(.:format)  players#getdata
```

Comment: what do you see when you do rake routes on your app?

Comment: This could be because you're only serving 'js' format from within controller. Try `http://localhost:3000/players/getdata.js`

Comment: @Raghu edited with rake routes

Comment: @user2769929 what about: `link_to "Show Chart", getdata_path(format: :js), remote: true, class: 'btn'`

Comment: @user2769929 no problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by changing routes to

```
get '/getdata' => 'players#getdata', as: :getdata
```